# Pattern for nested JavaScript and asynchronous functions/callback/Promises

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

I run into this kind of problem once in a while and at the moment I end up having to refactor a ton of code to work around the issue. My question is, is there a simpler pattern.

I get the impression this has been asked but I haven't found the answer. For example SO shows [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26613121/promises-in-recursive-asynchronous-functions) but it's clearly not the same question

The short pseudo code version is this. I start with imperative programming.

```
/**
 * node: some node in a tree of nodes
 * leave: an array on to which leaves will be pushed in depth first order
*/
function extractLeaves(node, leaves) {
   switch (node.type) {
     case 'leaf':
       leaves.push(node);
       break;
     case 'special':
       extractLeavesFromSpecial(node, leaves);
       break;
     default:
       extractLeavesFromChildren(node, leaves);
       break;
   }
}

function extractLeavesFromChildren(node, leaves) {
   node.children.forEach((child) => extractLeaves(child, leaves); 
}

function extractLeavesFromSpecial(node, leaves) {
   // skip leaves if they're this node is not special
   if (isSomethingIsReallySpecial(node)) {
     extractLeavesFromChildren(node, leaves);
   }
}

const leaves = [];
extractLeavesFromChildren(root, leaves);
```

As you can see it's imperative and recursive and it's working

Now all of a sudden I need to use some library that uses a callback deep in my recursions.

```
     case 'special':
       extractLeavesFromSpecial(node, leaves);
       break;
     case 'newSpecial':
       extractLeavesFromNewSpecial(node, leaves);
       break;


function extractLeavesFromNewSpecial(node, leaves) {
   someLibraryFunctionThatsAsync(node, callback);  // UGH!!!
   ....
```

The solution seems to be promises which is fine and I can do that.

My question is, do I have to refactor EVERY FUNCTION?

AFAICT when I run into an async required solution I suddenly have to re-write all functions to use promises all because just one of them ended up being async.

```
function extractLeaves(node) {
  return new Promise(resolve  => {
    switch (node.type) {
      case 'leaf':
        resolve([node]);
        break;
      case 'special':
        resolve(extractLeavesFromSpecial(node);
        break;
      case 'newSpecial':
        resolve(extractLeavesFromNewSpecial(node));
        break;
      default:
        resolve(extractLeavesFromChildren(node);
        break;
    }
  };
}

function extractLeavesFromChildren(node) {
  return Promise.all(node.children.map(child => {
     return extractLeaves(child, leaves);
  }).then(array => {
     // have to flatten as each element is an array
     // this will also magically filter out empty arrays
     return [].concat.apply([], arrays);
  });
}

function extractLeavesFromSpecial(node) {
   // skip leaves if they're this node is not special
   if (isSomethingIsReallySpecial(node)) {
     return extractLeavesFromChildren(node);
   } else {
     return Promise.resolve([]);   
   }
}

function extractLeavesFromNewSpecial(node) {
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
     someLibraryFunctionThatsAsync(node, (err, result) => {
       if (err) {
         reject(err);
       } else {
         resolve(...);  // not important what this returns to the point
       }
   }
   ....
}
```

In my actual code I have about 8 functions, is that really what's required or is there some simpler pattern?

Note: In my case not only did this seem to require refactoring everything. It seems to have made the solution slightly more complicated given that keeping the list of leaves flat requires filtering and checking that a nested path didn't end in a leaf where as the old method didn't have that problem. It's one line but it has to be considered where as before the issue just didn't exist.

The second problem is in the imperative method it was easy to process one tree at a time as in

```
lotsOfTrees.forEach(tree => {
  const leaves = [];
  extractLeaves(tree, leaves);
  // do something with leaves.
});
```

In the new on though each of those will be a promise and therefore without more work will get processed all at the same time (more memory) which means even more refactoring (not a big deal, it's like 3-6 lines of code to make promises run in sequence, rather it's that fact that sooooo much refactoring is required that's making question if I'm doing things wrong.

In one sense it seems pretty obvious that since one deep function needs to be async that effectively made all function above it async. That means all of those functions have to refactored. I'm just double checking I'm not missing something simpler.

Comment: asynchronism is contagious - you can't, ever, expect a synchronous result when a "called" function is asynchronous

Comment: Yea, like I mentioned at the bottom I guess that's the case. It's just no fun to to have to refactor a large amount of code. That rarely happened for me in other languages but JS libraries have so much async (I'm using an HTML parser that returns its result async) that it's common to have to re-write entire trees of functions because of this.

Comment: I know you mentioned it, I was affirming your point :p

Comment: look into async/await - you still have to refactor code, but refactoring for async/await can be a simpler task (because async/await allows asynchronous code to be written in an imperative style, apparently)

Comment: Yea, I'll do that. It is making me wonder though if I shouldn't just start writing every function to use a promise. Refactoring sucks (or feels like I messed up by not doing it right in the first place).

Comment: `start writing every function to use a promise` way overkill .. you just need to know when to do so

Comment: Notice that you can use the imperative approach (filling the `leaves` array, an *output parameter*) instead of the functional one (returning an array, concatenating the results of the recursive calls) with promises as well. Just keep the parameter and return promises that fulfill with undefined. However I really wouldn't recommend that.

Comment: Without making the inner promises more sync I'm not sure how that would work as any promise could resolve out of order and append itself out of place in the `leaves` array. I know the particular promises I wrote won't do that but I don't know when `someLibraryFunctionThatsAsync` will resolve. So I'm left with `Promises.all` collecting the results in order no?

Comment: Yes, for guaranteed order you would have to make all steps sequential in the imperative approach, that's exactly why I'm not recommending it. FP is just cleaner :-) However it does make the refactoring with `async`/`await` really trivial.